# How to change generated text's language in fzaninotto/Faker?

Tags: php, laravel, localization, faker

In Laravel I use Faker. ([fzaninotto/Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker))

Can't change locale(language) of generated texts.

My code:

```
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class MySeeder extends Seeder {    

    public function run() {
        $faker = Faker::create('ru_RU');

        $randomSentence = $faker->sentence();
        ...
    }
}
```

But, as result `$randomSentence` contains generated text from default locale ('en_EN').

*P.S.
Faker is updated. Folder '\vendor\fzaninotto\faker\src\Faker\Provider\ru_RU' contains Text.php*

Comment: I don't think you can

Answer (score 12):

The reason you're not getting Russian text from the `sentence()` method is that it's not using the text from `Text.php`.

The `sentence()` method is defined in [Lorem.php](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/blob/master/src/Faker/Provider/Lorem.php#L82) and uses the wordlist in that file. You either need to use the `realText()` method, or implement a Russian version of the wordlist (which the Faker author [has already said no to](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/pull/393))

In short, you need to use this line to get russian text:

```
$faker = Faker::create('ru_RU');
$randomSentence = $faker->realText();
```